# Two Random Numbers Without Repeating

Tags: r, random

I'm looking to make a set of two random numbers (e.g., [1,2], [3,12]) with the first number between 1-12, and the second between 1-4. I know how to sample the two numbers independently using:

```
sample(1:12, 1, replace = T)
sample(1:4, 1, replace = T)
```

but don't know how to create a system to determine if the pairing of the two numbers has already been rolled, and if so, roll again. Any tips!?

Thanks :)

Comment: How many pairs do you want to randomly draw without replication?

Comment: I’d like to roll one at a time until all unique pairs have been met.

Comment: So you want all unique pairs. That's why I asked. It's probably best to generate all the pairs using expand.grid and then shuffle them using sample

Comment: It's only 48 possible combinations. Can you not do a cross-join of 1:12 and 1:4 and pull a sample(48) giving you the sequence of draws?

Comment: Use set to create an unique set of random numbers and combination to generate pairs

Comment: I think using @dason’s suggestion makes the most sense for me. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't scale happily (in case you need large-scale simulation), you can do this:

```r
set.seed(42)
di2 <- sample(setdiff(1:4, di1 <- sample(1:12, size = 1)), size = 1)
c(di1, di2)
# [1] 1 2
```

- The inner (`di1`) assignment takes the first from `1:12`, so far so good.
- We then set-diff `1:4` from this so that the second sampling only has candidates that are not equal to `di1`;
- The outer (`di2`) assignment samples from `1:4` without `di1` if it was within 1-4.

While not an authoritative *proof* of correctness,

```r
rand <- replicate(100000, local({ di2 <- sample(setdiff(1:4, di1 <- sample(1:12, size=1)), size = 1); c(di1, di2); }))
dim(rand)
# [1]      2 100000
any(rand[1,] == rand[2,])
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for sth like:

```
library(tidyverse)
expand.grid(1:12,1:4) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  slice_sample (n = 5, replace = FALSE)
```